# Clojure: = vs ==

Tags: clojure, equality

I'm struggling with understanding why

```
(= 1 1.0)
```

evaluates to `false` whereas

```
(== 1 1.0)
```

evaluates to `true`. According to the [docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/==), `==` seems to be only working on numbers but other than that there doesn't seem much difference. So, what am I missing?

Comment: REPL is your best friend. (doc =) (doc ==)

Comment: This returns "nil" under lighttable, would you know why?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`==` checks for mathematical equivalence. `=` with numbers checks for equivalence in a way that is agnostic to size where applicable, but is strict about representation:

```
user> (= (float 1.0) (double 1.0))
true
user> (= (int 1) (byte 1))
true
user> (= (int 1) (double 1))
false
user> (= 0.5 (/ 1 2))
false
user> (== 0.5 (/ 1 2))
true
```

assumedly, the reasoning is that the representation of floating point can lose precision, and should not be treated as equivalent to integral or exact representations.